# How to disable right click action when using QRubberBand?

Tags: qt, qchart, qchartview

Whenever I press the right-click button, it sort of zooms out a little instead I want to restore the initial position of my QChart whenever I press the Right-Click. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set the Rubberband to "no" for the chartView, so that it does react to your positioning, but no zoom.

```
setRubberBand(QChartView::NoRubberBand);
```

Comment: Thanks, Marcel for your reply. This worked but for the second part, how do I restore my initial position and zooming? I am using chart()->scroll(0,0) and chart()->zoomReset() in the MouseClickEvent() when right click is pressed but it isn't working.